# sh: pass through file by character and edit it

Tags: bash, shell, loops, file, sh

I know how to pass through a file char by char with sh:

```
while read -n1 char; do ... done < file.tmp
```

but, how can we edit, add string, to the file, at the level of such character, in our loop?

for example:

```
while read -n1 char; do
    if [ ... ] ; then
       echo "something" here in our temp file
    fi
done < tmp.tmp
```

Comment: Think about it. How do you expect to read and write from the same file at the same time? Output to a temporary file instead.

Comment: OH, but yes! of course! it's solved ^^ thanks ^^ sometimes, we lack perspective on obvious things

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing the same file at the same time is not possible that way. Instead, print the result into a temporary file and rename it later.

With `printf %s ...` you can print a single character without a linebreak. You also have to modify the `read` such that it doesn't swallow the whitespace from your file.

```
while IFS= read -d '' -N 1 char; do
    printf %s "$char"
    if [ ... ] ; then
       echo "This text and a linebreak will be inserted after $char"
    fi
done < inputfile > outputfile
mv outputfile inputfile
```

However, this approach is probably very slow and tedious to write. I'd reccommend a tool like `sed` or `awk` instead.

> after each `\commandA{...}`, add `\commandB{...}`. so, search `\commandA{`, wait the end brace `}` of `commandA` [...], then add `\commandB{`

If there are no nested braces and linebreaks inside `\commandA{...}` then this `sed` command will do:

```
sed -Ei 's#\\commandA\{[^}]*\}#&\\commandB{...}#g' file
```

Otherwise you might want to switch to `perl`. Here only escaped braces (e.g. `\{` or `` \verb`{` `` ) are not handled.

```
perl -p -0777 -i -e 's#\\commandA(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?-1))*+\})#$&\\commandB{...}#g' file
```

Alternatively, you don't have to do the replacement at all. Instead, modify the LaTeX command `\commandA` to include `\commandB` automatically. In your preamble write

```tex
\let\oldcommandA\commandA
\renewcommand{\commandA}[1]{\oldcommandA{#1}\commandB{...}}
```

Comment: Yes, passing through a file with a loop is not a good option, but  i don't know how to produce my idea with sed or awk

Comment: If you precisely describe what you want to do I might be able to do it for you. An example input and expected output are often better for communication this stuff.

Comment: it is really quite courteous of you!

after each `\commandA{...}`, add `\commandB{...}`. 

so, search `\commandA{`, wait the end brace `}` of commandA (the difficult point with sed (i don't know very munch awk)), then add `\commandB{`

Comment: Anyway, I can do it easily with a small loop. But `printf` doesn't copy the line breaks. And `echo` makes break line after each char. And `echo -n` doens't work...

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. But, the point is there is nested braces inside commandA. That is the difficulty I think. If there were no nested braces, your function would work perfectly!

Comment: @ThomasLeger It isn't `printf` that swallows the linebreaks but `read`. I fixed that part. ++ With nested braces `sed` isn't the right tool. I'd use `perl` instead. I try to come up with something.

Comment: Yes, perl has reccursive implementation, with the -p argument, among others things

Comment: oh, that is `read` he betrayer. I look at the `read` manpage to understand why the `-d`. Thanks for all!

Comment: @ThomasLeger I added a perl solution that should work in most cases. Remove the `-i` to check the result without modifying the file.

Comment: well,  thanks . I will see that soon. and I make a small return

Comment: Yes, your perl function seems to works very well. But, could you explain in detail how it works? I don't like copy/paste the work of others.

Otherwise, for the latex tips you mentionned, I know indeed how to use renewcomand. my problem is a different one. i'm trying a weird export to HTML thing. anyway!

Comment: The content of `{...}` is a mixture (= `(...|...)*`) of stuff without braces (= `[^{}]+`) and other `{`-`}`-pairs for which we use the recursive regex `(?-1)` referring to the outer group `(\{...\})` again. However, I cannot explain why we need non-capturing (= `?:` and `++`). I really tried to write this myself, but then ended up copying it from the [perl manual](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?PARNO)-(?-PARNO)-(?+PARNO)-(?R)-(?0)).